# can't return jsx in nested map react javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested-loops, react-props

I've received from props data json like this:

```
uploadResponse:{
        request:{
            DONE:3,
            LOADING:2,
            HEADERS_RECEIVED:1
        },
        response:{
            config:{
                alive:true
            },
            data:{
                crs:"65",
                message_number_1:"content of message 1",    
                message_number_2:"content of message 2",    
                message_number_3:"content of message 3",    
            },
            headers:{
                content_type:"type 1"
            },
            request:{
                req:1
            }
        }
    }
```

and want to return in jsx "crs" and "message_number_x"
then I map through this JSON object like this:

```
return(
<>
 {props.uploadResponse !== undefined ?
                    Object.values(props.uploadResponse).map((response) => {
                        return(
                            <>
                                {Object.values(response).map((data) => {
                                    return(
                                        <>
                                            {Object.values(data).map((item) => {
                                                return(
                                                    <>
                                                        {item}
                                                        </>
                                                )
                                            })}
                                            </>
                                    )
                                })}
                                </>
                        )
                    }) : null }
</>
)
```

But nothing is return, anyone know what is a problem? When I get log from console then I see item in inspector.

Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you supplied a full example of the code, it's not completely clear what value props will have from your example. I tried to paste your code and run it and it actually seems to work after I glued the missing pieces together so I guess something is wrong earlier in your code and not in the render. This is an example of how you can make your code work at least, hope it helps you in the right direction.

```
export default function App({ uploadResponse }) {
  if (uploadResponse === undefined) return null;
  return (
    <>
      {Object.values(uploadResponse.response.data).map((item) => item)}
    </>
  );
}
```

And where you use the component:

```
const data = {
  uploadResponse: {
    request: {
      DONE: 3,
      LOADING: 2,
      HEADERS_RECEIVED: 1
    },
    response: {
      config: {
        alive: true
      },
      data: {
        crs: "65",
        message_number_1: "content of message 1",
        message_number_2: "content of message 2",
        message_number_3: "content of message 3"
      },
      headers: {
        content_type: "type 1"
      },
      request: {
        req: 1
      }
    }
  }
};

<App uploadResponse={data.uploadResponse} />
```

Answer (score 0):

When I implement this like Your idea, I've received error that uploadResponse.response is undefined. When I look console log I saw:

```
props.uploadResponse: {"response":{"data":{"crs":"type","message_number_1":"#/features/1/properties: 16 schema violations found","message_number_0":"#/features/0/properties: 16 schema violations found","message_number_4":"#/features/4/properties: 16 schema violations found","message_number_3":"#/features/3/properties: 16 schema violations found","status":"false","message_number_2":"#/features/2/properties: 16 schema violations found"},"status":400,"statusText":"","headers":{"content-type":"application/json"},"config":{"transformRequest":{},"transformResponse":{},"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"method":"post","url":"http://localhost:8080/admin_panel/upload_file","data":{},"cancelToken":{"promise":{}},"responseType":"json","withCredentials":false},"request":{}},"request":{}}
```

Comment: I need to implement 3x useState first useState get props.uploadResponse , then second useState get first useState.response and third useStae get second useState.data , finally from this last useState I can use map method and iterate through all items... Any optimize?